# Mount path to Azure IoT Edge module

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge

I followed the example from the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-develop-python-module and was playing around a bit.

I tried to mount a path into the IoT module container like I would do in docker but I didn't succeed. I added the following to the createOptions in the deployments.template.json:

```
"createOptions": {
    "Volumes": {
        "D:\\test":"/test"
    }
}
```

This results in a RUNTIME RESPONSE: 400 - The deployment configuration is malformed or invalid.

My questions:

- Is it even possible to mount a path from the host to IoTEdge modules like one would do in docker?
- If yes, how?
- Where can I find a reference of all the createOptions arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is indeed possible to use mounts. You can find an example of how to use them in the creation options in the SQL Server tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-store-data-sql-server#add-a-sql-server-container

`"createOptions": "{\"HostConfig\": {\"Mounts\": [{\"Target\": \"/var/opt/mssql\",\"Source\": \"sqlVolume\",\"Type\": \"volume\"}],\"PortBindings\": {\"1433/tcp\": [{\"HostPort\": \"1401\"}]}}}"`