# Azure Stream Analytics module on Iot Edge not reported by device after deployment

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-edge

I created an ASA module and deployed it through `Set Modules` but on `reported by device` column is assigned `NO`.

What is the reason and meaning of this status after succesfull deployment and how can I fix it ?

These are my modules
[image]

and this is the `Route` for the Stream Analytics module:
[image]

**Update** : Also this module has aditional input with absolute path reference data.

I tried to deploy another seperate ASA module using simple Job with input, output and it works. So the problem must be in `reference data` path ?

I have another module which downloads a file in `./file.txt`. (This should be in /app/file.txt ?)

I want the ASA module to read already downloaded file as a **local reference data**. What reference data directory should I put in the `job`. Now I'm trying with `/app/file.txt`

Comment: Hi. Can you confirm whether the ASA job runs successfully on the device? You can use the following command on the device to check logs: docker logs ModuleName

Comment: Hi @Jean-Sébastien , I can't see it on my local simulated device typing `iotedge list`. It's visible only on the Azure portal with `Reported by device - NO`

Comment: I see, in this case, it seems the deployment was not successful (device offline) or the module had some issue and the container was stopped. Can you look if the ASA container was ever launched by running docker ps -a ? If you see ASA in the list, can you get the log for it, otherwise can you send the logs of the IoT Edgehub and Edgeagent to our DL for investigation: askASA@microsoft.com

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien I've noticed some progress with the issue and updated the question. And I don't see my module  after typing `docker ps -a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"no" in "Reported by device" means this module doesn't has any status to report, usually it indicates that the module isn't created successfully. In your case, there must be error when bind the path of reference data to container during container creation.

what is your host os and container os?
If your host os matches container os, please use the absolute path instead of ./
If you are running a Linux container on windows host, please first create a volume, populate the reference data to the volume and provide the absolute path in volume eg. Vol1/file1.txt

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I got it. One last thing. After creating the volume, after inspection it looks like [this](http://prntscr.com/lcmubq). There are different issues that discuss this, but how should CreateOptions look like ? It's confusing because the `Docker Engine API` has `Volumes` property and some examples in these issues use `Mounts` property. A sample would be really appreciated.

Comment: nevermind, found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52572289/mount-path-to-azure-iot-edge-module?rq=1)

Comment: When you import an ASA module from iotedge portal, we should auto generate "CreateOption" to bind a volume to container. Please let me know if it didn't.